# How do I view the log for a file that is part of a Git subtree?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I'm using [Git subtree](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/about-git-subtree-merges) without the squash option. If I do `git log --follow -- filename` it shows nothing and if I do `git log -- filename` it only shows single log.

How do I view the *entire* log for files in a subtree?

Comment: Did you use the subtree _merge strategy_ (which is the topic of the [help article](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/about-git-subtree-merges) you linked) or the [subtree subcommand](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt) (which is the thing that has a squash option)? Can you provide the exact command line and output?

Answer (score 1):

Since subtree commits are actually all merge commits, you need to provide the [`-m` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--m).

> for each merge parent, a separate log entry and diff is generated.

Try this:

```
git blame -m --follow -- filename
```